# Trying to get an Excel document through ajax, running into async issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm adding JavaScript to a SharePoint and I'm trying to write a function that gets an Excel document, or rather the data in it, from a library. I've already figured out how to do that, but the files in question are too large to be returned. I've considered manually setting the size limit for ajax, but I haven't found any way to do this, so Plan B is to send a query for each row

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
   readFileRow(libraryUrl, "FileName.xlsx", "Sheet1", 1, "E", [])
   .done(function(cells) {
    console.log(xmlToJson(cells.documentElement));
   });
  });

/**
  * Reads a file in SharePoint Library via ExcelRest and returns the document
  *
  * @params string libraryUrl
  * @params string fileName
  * @params string sheetName
  * @params int rowNum
  * @params string lastColumn
  * @params string[][] finalResults
  *
  * @returns string[][]
 **/
 function readFileRow(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum, lastColumn, finalResults) {
  var fileUrl = libraryUrl + "/" + fileName + "/Model/Ranges('" + sheetName + "!A" + rowNum + "|" + lastColumn + rowNum + "')?$format=atom";

  return $.ajax({
   url: fileUrl,
   type: "GET",
   error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
   },
  }).done(function(data) {
   jsonData = xmlToJson(data.documentElement);
   cells = serializeRange(jsonData);

   if(cells) {
    finalResults.push(cells);
    rowNum++;
    finalResults = readFileRow(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum, lastColumn, finalResults);
   }

   return $.when(finalResults);
  });
 }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get around the async issue by calling the function recursively when the request comes back with data, meaning that it has to keep running. When I place a console.log() just before the return, I can see that it is compiling the results as I need it to. However, the return from calling readFileRow() is coming back before the process finishes and consists of the response from the very first ajax query, having apparently not been run through the .done() function. I've tried removing the return in front of the ajax call, but this only causes an exception, since the return is no longer thenable and thus doesn't have a .done() function.

Can anyone spot what's wrong with this function? Async functions aren't my forte and I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the answer was simply that I didn't fully understand what various methods related to async functions were doing. I restructured the function in the following way and got it to work as expected:

```
    $("#updateClusterDetails").click(function() {
        console.log("Update initiated");
        var baseFile = "AIF%20Test.xlsx";

        $.when(readFileRow(libraryUrl, baseFile, "Sheet1", 1, "E", new Array())).then(function(results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    });

/**
 * Reads a file in SharePoint Library via ExcelRest and returns the document
 *
 * @params string libraryUrl
 * @params string fileLocation
 *
 * @returns Document/HTML
**/
function readFile(libraryUrl, fileLocation) {
    // The base url for the SharePoint document library
    var fileUrl = libraryUrl + fileLocation;

    return $.ajax({
        url: fileUrl,
        type: "GET",
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
        success: function(data) {
            return $.when(data);
        }
    });
}

    /**
 * Reads a series of rows in an Excel file in SharePoint Library via ExcelRest and returns the row data
 *
 * @params string libraryUrl
 * @params string fileName
 * @params string sheetName
 * @params int rowNum
 * @params string lastColumn
 * @params string[][] currentResults
 *
 * @returns string[][]
**/
function readFileRows(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum, lastColumn, currentResults) {
    var fileUrl = "/" + fileName + "/Model/Ranges('" + sheetName + "!A" + rowNum + "|" + lastColumn + rowNum + "')?$format=atom";

    return readFile(libraryUrl, fileUrl)
    .then(function(data) {
        jsonData = xmlToJson(data.documentElement);
        cells = serializeRange(jsonData);

        if(!cells) {
            return $.when(currentResults);
        }
        else {
            currentResults.push(cells);
            return $.when(readFileRow(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum + 1, lastColumn, currentResults));
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test your exact implementation, but here's how I've done it previously:

For the ajax call in `readFileRow`, use `.then` instead of `.done` as this will return a promise for the return value of the `.then` function instead of the ajax object itself.

Then you can just return `finalResults` without the when, and the recursive and initial calls to `readFileRow` need to `await` this return.

I'm not super well-versed in promises and async coding either but this is how I've done similar things previously.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
 let cells = await readFileRow(libraryUrl, "FileName.xlsx", "Sheet1", 1, "E", [])
 console.log(xmlToJson(cells.documentElement));
});

/**
  * Reads a file in SharePoint Library via ExcelRest and returns the document
  *
  * @params string libraryUrl
  * @params string fileName
  * @params string sheetName
  * @params int rowNum
  * @params string lastColumn
  * @params string[][] finalResults
  *
  * @returns string[][]
 **/
 function readFileRow(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum, lastColumn, finalResults) {
  var fileUrl = libraryUrl + "/" + fileName + "/Model/Ranges('" + sheetName + "!A" + rowNum + "|" + lastColumn + rowNum + "')?$format=atom";

  return $.ajax({
   url: fileUrl,
   type: "GET",
   error: function (request, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
   },
  }).then(function(data) {
   jsonData = xmlToJson(data.documentElement);
   cells = serializeRange(jsonData);

   if(cells) {
    finalResults.push(cells);
    rowNum++;
    finalResults = await readFileRow(libraryUrl, fileName, sheetName, rowNum, lastColumn, finalResults);
   }

   return finalResults;
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the calls concurrent (wait until to request to return and only then call to next one), you can call them in parallel using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

While the code below is not using your code at all (because I can't make it actually work), it demonstrate how it should act. If it's not reflecting your case 100%, let me know.

The logic is:

1. Fetching the total number of rows so we could know how much request we should create - we have to wait for this request because we need its data for the rest of the requests.
2. Making an array with all the promises and pass it to `Promise.all`. The `then` will return all the data combined.

Let me know if the example is not clear..

```js
const data = new Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => ({
  foo: `bar${i}`
}));

/* simulate the ajax call to get the total number of rows
 TODO replace it with the actual call */
function getRowsCount() {
  return Promise.resolve(data.length);
}

/* simulate the ajax call to get row's data by index
 TODO replace it with the actual call*/
function getRow(index) {
  return Promise.resolve(data[index]);
}

function getData() {
  return getRowsCount()
    .then(rowCount => {
      const allRequests = new Array(rowCount).fill().map((_, index) => getRow(index));
      return Promise.all(allRequests)
    });
}

getData().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: This didn't really help me much. I don't think your necessarily wrong, but I wasn't able to get whatever lesson you were teaching to apply to my code.

Comment: Fair enough. Although it's important one in performance wise..